# Windows 10: telnet - Openwall GNU/*/Linux telnetd running on an open port normal?

Tags: ports, windows-10

I noticed my internet connection was acting a little strange (stuttering up abruptly seemingly randomly), so I thought I'd see what's using it using Zenmap.

I ran "Intense scan" using the latest version of Zenmap and set the target to my modem's default gateway ip.

5 ports open 2 filtered. Most of the service names check out (netbios-ssn, microsoft-ds, icslap, http (Router name as Version)...), but there's this one I find really suspicious:

`23  tcp   open   telnet   Openwall GNU/*/Linux telnetd`

When I search for windows 10 and telnet nothing noteworthy pops up. If I search Windows 10 Openwall... I get nothing with both those keywords in it.
Checking out Openwall, I'm greeted with this Jack the Ripper bit about fast password cracking.

I've never installed any such software directly, and checking out the running services in task manager there's nothing by the name of "telnet" or "Openwall".

Any kind soul willing to tell me if I should freak out or not?

Comment: Please clarify what exactly the target of your scan was? It is very confused. Why is Win10 a factor? Why are you checking your local running services?

Comment: Are you using a router which might have an open telnetd? Have you tried connecting to the host using `telnet yourip`? What does it say? Is your _"modem's default gateway IP"_ even your machine?

Comment: If you look on Openwall's site, you will see that they have their own version of Linux:  http://www.openwall.com/Owl/ THAT'S what you scanned, and it's that machine's telnet you scanned.

Comment: smokedispenser: "Are you using a router which might have an open telnetd?"  This is definitely possible.  I'm living in an apartment in Japan and contracted an ISP independently.  They provided me with the router and had someone set it up on some hub in the apartment (a thing for ISP's to track internet usage in specific rooms).  In short, I don't know, but the ISP is one of the few major carriers.  "Have you tried connecting to the host using telnet yourip? What does it say?" Sorry, I don't know how. "Is your "modem's default gateway IP" even your machine?" I think so. It's a private network.

Comment: schroeder: Thank you very much for taking the time to respond again.
 
"If you look on Openwall's site, you will see that they have their own version of Linux: openwall.com/Owl THAT'S what you scanned, and it's that machine's telnet you scanned."  I own no machines with Linux installed. Unless I plug in my wifi router to the modem, I should be the only machine using the router.  That Openwall GNU/*/Linux telnetd shows up with or without the wifi router connected.

Comment: schroeder: Sorry for not being more clear. A_Learner is correct, I tried to scan my default gateway IP Address from inside my local network. I typed "ipconfig" in dos cmd, and put the first default gateway IP In the "Target" field."Why is Win10 a factor?" I read some threads saying that internet "handling" has changed over the life of windows, so I figured it may be of use to say I'm running Win10. I take it it's irrelevant. I'm sorry. "Why are you checking your local running services?" Some "how-to site" recommended cross-checking local services with services associated with ports in zenmap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little unclear (and I don't have the reputation required for comments) so I'll assume that what you're referring to is having scanned your default gateway IP Address from inside your local network.

If that is the case then what you are seeing is likely just a telnet service which can be used to manage your router and this on its own would not be cause for concern, as it's a common port used for that purpose.

The reference to openwall will be based on the banner returned by the service when zenmap connected to it.  you can test this by using a telnet client and connecting to your gateway IP address.

As the comments have noted, whilst openwall does product the john password cracking software, it does also produce linux software called OwL http://www.openwall.com/Owl/ which includes a telnet server.

One other point is that if you need to adminster your router/modem you should ideally use SSH rather than telnet......

Comment: Thank you for the thorough response, A_Learner. Yes, as you surmised, I entered the default gateway IP (that was coughed up by running "ipconfig" in cmd) into the Target field of zenmap.  I think it's my local network.  My Windows 10 network is set to private, and I made my PC Set to Discoverable so I can use my Android as a remote.  I've never installed ANY openwall product directly though.  Hmm, unfortunately, I don't know how to use a telnet client or connect it to my gateway IP add.  Heh, I know nothing of telnet or SSH...I'm sorry about all this, I could've sworn I mentioned I am newb...

Comment: Might you know of a way to make sure that this telnet service is related to/employed by my ISP (its modem or whatever) and not some network savvy unknown party in the apartment snaggin' one of my ports?

Answer (score -1):

You didn't scan your system. Run a local scan by giving **local host** (127.0.0.1) address in your scanner. It gives best results about ports.

For more effective results, you can use Belarc Software to know which software you have installed.

If you scan your default gateway, then the target is your modem/router. If you scan default gateway which was presented in your modem/router then your target becomes your ISP.

Comment: That does not show the ports open on the internet-facing interface but localhost.

Comment: Venkatesh, thank you for that info.  Yes, I believe I did scan my "default gateway" according to cmd's "ipconfig" at least. I've used Belarc before.  What software should I check for using it if I want to find out who/what is using my modem?

Comment: You can observe the connections by observing SYSLOG of a router/switch. If you want to restrict the network access who are trying to connect, then you can use MAC Address Filter.

Comment: Is it home network or office network?  If it is office network you can use Splunk (free upto 500mb) or any other syslog monitoring software (In this you have to enable syslog service).  If it is home purpose you can look at logs tab in the router/switch.

Comment: Venkatesh Chinta: Thanks again for your help!  It's a home network.  I'll look into how to add mac address filters.

Comment: Venkatesh Chinta: Thanks again for your help!  It's a home network.  I'll look into how to add mac address filters in an attempt to have a little more control over what can access the network. That Openwall GNU/*/Linux telnetd versioned telnet service I'm suspicious of is always on, on the same port whenever I run the scan (then again I turn on my modem at about the same everyday).  It's likely normal as A_Learner&smokedispenser say.     I just find it strange that a modem distributed by an ISP in Japan would employ an opensource service on one of the ports...  Is it normal?

Comment: Telnet is used to administrate your device remotely. For example I have a server in a remote place. Now I want to configure my system from my home. Then I don't want go to remote place. I can manage my server remotely using Telnet Service. Telnet Service communication between you and server is plain text, but SSH is an encrypted session of Telnet.    Now your network is home based. ISP assigned a private IP to your router/gateway/modem.  No other people unable to access your telnet, except your network users (means users behind the router/modem).

Comment: For MAC filtering **https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n740cba0kqM**  watch this link.